# List package maintainer on Fedora?

Tags: fedora, yum, packages

I need to contact the package maintainers for Crypto++ to inform them of a commit to fix a CVE. Under Debian and Ubuntu, I can `apt-cache show libcrypto++ | grep Maintainer` to get current and past maintainers.

Unfortunately, Yum does not provide the same information with `yum info`:

```
$ yum info cryptopp | grep -i Maintainer
$ yum info cryptopp | grep -i '@'
$
```

Oddly, I'm not getting obvious hits when Googling: [fedora show package maintainer](https://www.google.com/search?q=fedora+show+package+maintainer). For example, the number one hit, Fedora's [Package Maintainers wiki page](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Category:Package_Maintainers?rd=PackageMaintainers), does ***not*** tell me how to list a maintainer. (For some reason, I expected a Super User or Stack Overflow answer to jump out at me).

How do I list the package maintainer for Fedora? I would also like Red Hat if anyone knows how to do it (and its different from Fedora).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can just send email to `PACKAGE-maintainers@fedoraproject.org` but the normally preferred method (especially as this CVE already seems to be public) would be to enter a bug at https://bugzilla.redhat.com/enter_bug.cgi?product=Fedora.

The literal answer to your question is to look the package up in the package database at https://admin.fedoraproject.org/pkgdb/package/cryptopp which will give you the usernames which you can then use to send mail to `USER@fedoraproject.org`. I don't think the owner information is recorded in the RPM metadata at all, other than indirectly via the changelog.

Comment: Thanks Tom. I don't believe I have an account on redhat.com, so that's not a viable alternative. Also, Fedora's package page list names (like *mstevens*), but it does not provide an email address. I ended up sending an email to the *security@* well known email address from [RFC 2142](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2142.txt). Hopefully, they are monitoring it (I believe so since it did not generate a bounce report).

Comment: I explained how to send email to a user name...